# Email Formular in Wordpress footer

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i allready serched but didnt find an answer to my problem. I have to make a wordpress site. I usually just write my sites with html, php, js,... but for that project i need wordpress so i started learning how it works and how to make my own theme. Everything worked perfectly out but now i want to intigrate a Contact formular in my footer. I usually would do that with PHP sending an Email to the admin adress whe somebody fills out a form. But taht just doesnt seem to work out.

Does somebody has an idee how to code it in a wordpress theme?
Best regard
Paul

BTW im not a nativ english speaker please dont criticise it too hard;)

Answer (score 0):

You must first make sure that sending email is allowed on your server.

Then you can use *[wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)* function in order to send messages.

Example:

```
$to = 'sendto@example.com';
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
 
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```